# How to know the commands being passed when compiling with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, command-line-interface, eclipse-juno

I am new to `Java` programming, especially with eclipse. I would really like to know how the java programs are actually getting compiled, it would help me in knowing the `Java` command line interface better. So, I want to know if there is a way to know exactly which commands are being sent along with the **switches** to compile and run the `java` program?

Comment: In eclipse, go project -> run configuration.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis- I can only change switches and other things in Run Configuration, but I want something like, when I click on `Run` button, I should be able to see the commands which are being sent to console.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure that you are taking up a J2SE edition of Java programming which should be a fundamental to you. Let me start with giving you an glimpse of a Java Program:

```
class Greetings
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
     System.out.println("The first character of the command line " + args[0]);
}}
```

So let's go thru what I meant by each line.

- The class indicates beginning of the class which would contain all of
  the methods to be into.
- The "public static void main" indicates the main method which would contain the method to be executed.
- And the characters found in the brackets of the only method is known as parameters.
- Those parameters are passed from the command line to the program where they could be worked on depending on the program.

And with this, let me advise you to take up a read on this page for more on Java (J2SE).

http://www.w3resource.com/java-tutorial/java-program-structure.php

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

Unless there are some Eclipse logs that track that (check your installation folder), I doubt Eclipse shows it to you through the IDE. Compiling and running java mostly comes down to two commands:

[**javac**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html)

You compile by executing

`javac -cp <your classpath/libs> <your source folder>`

[**java**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/java.html)

You run your program by executing

`java -cp <classpath> <Class with main method> <main method arguments>`

Comment: Isn't there any extension available to do this thing?

Comment: @PrateekSingla I don't know of one. You can search Eclipse's source code, it is freely available. The above is what you will most likely find.